# Ansible adhoc command default user

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

Just exploring ansible and i am using ansible adhoc command

hosts file for ansible:

> [cloud] 
> node  ansible_ssh_private_key_file=myfile.pem
>   ansible_user=ec2-user

```
$ ansible node -m ping -u ec2-user > works
$ ansible node -m ping > does not work
```

My doubt is if it is picking up the ansible_ssh_private_key_file from the hosts file why is it not picking the ansible_user from the same?

Comment: Any pointers towards where I am getting it wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

With Ansible version 1.9.x and earlier you should use `ansible_ssh_user`, while in Ansible 2.0 and later `ssh` is removed from all `ansible_ssh_*` variables and they are now shorter e.g. `ansible_user`, `ansible_host`, and `ansible_port`.